# Op amp design for charge pump

Tags: operational-amplifier, charge-pump

This is the charge pump design from Razavi. [image: Charge pump]

I want to design the opamp for the circuit, a design for which is as given below.

[image: Opamp]

Is the op-amp architecture correct for this circuit, since it requires a rail to rail input swing? Also, how do we increase the gain of that op amp?

Comment: When you want to design something the first thing you need to do is get your **requirements** clear. That opamp has a rail-to-rail input stage (it does not require it, it is a **feature**). But do you **need** a rail-to-rail input opamp for the chargepump ? There are situations when you do not need that. **Why** do you want to increase the gain of the opamp ? How much gain do you need ? What happens when you have too much or too little gain ? Too much gain always makes stability more of an issue.

Comment: It is mentioned in Razavi to use a rail to rail op-amp.

Comment: And you just take his word for it ? Any idea **why** Razavi would write that ? I can think of situations when a rail-to-rail opamp is not needed making the opamp's design simpler. If you want to be a circuit designer always try to find out **why this, why that** if your excuse is: "Because the guy says so." Then you will never be a good circuit designer. Understanding **why** is key to good circuit design.